# Cobertura 2.7 and Java 1.8 -issues with Junit 4 test cases-Exception

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am using cobertura-maven-plugin-2.7 and I am getting an error when I do a maven build.

But when I run the Junit test case independently it is successfully executed.

Environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00) Java version: 1.8.0_51, 
vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: F:\Java\JDK8_51\jre Default locale: en_US, 
platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7", 
version: "6.1", 
arch: "amd64", 
family: "dos" Junit 4.12
```

**ERROR TRACE:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CustomClass.<clinit>(CustomClass.java:33)
```

> at line 33:(shown below)-LoggerFactory(of type
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory) is null

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(CustomClass.class);
```

UPDATE:

Hi.Thanks I did make some changes to code to remove the "static" references which are not needed.But I still have issues in mocking any of the interfaces which work fine if I run individually using Junit but fail when I do a build using cobertura.Any inputs please?
Sorry for not posting another question as the issue of not able to build using cobertura 2.7 still persists but in another form.

Comment: I am using Jmockit 1.7 for unit test cases

Answer (score 1):

You might have run into a bug: [Instrumented classes throw NPE during static initialization](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/172).

Comment: Hi.Thanks I did make some changes to code to resolve the "static" references.But I still have issues in mocking some interfaces which work fine if I run individually using Junit but fail when I do a build using cobertura.Any inputs please?

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others may benefit from it. If you have another problem, please [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Comments are not the right place for this.